# needed aggregate functions for mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

i am newbie in mongo and manage to write simple queries .
can some one help me writing complex queries for below data

> {
>       "deviceId" : "58a588a1ed3b863d6dd5693b",
>       "data" : {
>           "Datetime" : "2017-03-02 05:06:08",
>           "Temperature" : "25",
>           "Humidity" : "50"
>       } }

i need to write queries for 1 hour avg for temeprature and two hour average for temperature

Comment: take a look at [**$hour**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) operator. First split your date in year/month/day/hour in a `$project` stage, then compute average using `$avg` in a `$group` stage

Comment: ok i will look into $hour operator and let you know